# How to map two foreign keys mapping to the same primary key column in Hibernate (one-to-one)?

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa

I am new to Java and Hibernate and I am trying to map the following scenario in Hibernate (using annotations).

I am dealing with the following two tables ( related to some ETL type of tasks).

Tasks
    |-TaskId
    |-SourceDatabase (FK to the Databases table)
    |-TargetDatabase (FK to the Databases table)

Databases
     |-DatabaseId (PK)
    |-TaskId   (FK to the Tasks table)
    |-Other database details.

Each task has a sourceDatabase and a targetDatabase. Also each Database is related to **only one Task**.
How can I map to this model in Hibernate using one-to-one mapping.

```
@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    int taskId;

    //How to map  using one-to-one mapping??
    Database sourceDB;
    //how to map  using one-to-one mapping??
    Database targetDB;
}

@Entity
public class Database implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    int databaseId;

    //How to map using one-to-one mapping??
    Task task;  
}
```

I have removed all unnecessary code from the above code sample.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand, you have 3 separate one-to-one relationships with their respective foreign keys, so you can map them as normal one-to-one relationships:

```
@Entity
public class Task implements Serializable
{
...
    @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "SourceDatabase")
    Database sourceDB;

    @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "TargetDatabase")
    Database targetDB;
}

@Entity
public class Database implements Serializable
{
     ...
     @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "TaskId")
    Task task;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you Axtavt! I was confused about the @mappedby annotation. Not sure when @mappedby is required?

Comment: @crazyfor: `mappedBy` is used to link two sides of the same bidirectional relationship. Since your relationships use their own foreign keys, you have separate unidirectional relationsips and don't need `mappedBy`.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching using mappedBy --for  two foreign keys mapping to the same primary key column in Hibernate (one-to-one)?(for bidirectional relationship )

scenario with slight modification--as given below

```
Tasks
    |-TaskId
    |-SourceDatabase (FK to the Databases table)
    |-TargetDatabase (FK to the Databases table)

Databases
    |-DatabaseId (PK)
    |-Other database details.
```

I have took the code from @axtavt and modified for mappedBy so it will be helpful for others

```
  @Entity
   public class Task implements Serializable
   {
    ...
      @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "SourceDatabase")
      Database sourceDB;

      @OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "TargetDatabase")
      Database targetDB;
   }

   @Entity
   public class Database implements Serializable
  {
     ...
       @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "sourceDB")
       Task taskSource; 

      @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},mappedBy = "targetDB")
      Task taskTarget; 
   }
```