# JPA Hibernate two foreign keys to the same table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I've found two topics [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754243/how-to-map-two-foreign-keys-mapping-to-the-same-primary-key-column-in-hibernate) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954787/hibernate-with-two-foreign-keys-from-same-table-annotation), but still cannot populate it to my case. I have an `Account`. I can do `Payments` from one account to another. For that purpose I want to store `payer_account_id` and `receiver_account_id` in `Payments` table. How can I map that using Annotations?
[image]

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Double balance;

    //mapping here to Payments Entity
    private ???

}


@Entity
    public class Payments {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
         private Long id;
        private Double ammount;

        //mapping here to Account Entity
        private Account payerAccount;

        //mapping here to Account Entity
        private Account receiverAccount;

    }
```

Comment: To me it looks like you only need to regular onetomany/manytoone mappings. There is nothing special so far.

Comment: so they are (currently) unidirectional relations, and? if you want them bidirectional then you add Payments objects at the other side. Don't see an issue

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It seems to be an one-to-many relations. If you want to do a bidirectional relations use these annotations.

```
@Entity
public class Account {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Double balance;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="payerAccount", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Payments> payers;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="receiverAccount", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<Payments> receivers;


    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */
}

@Entity
public class Payments {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private Double ammount;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="payer_account_id")
    private Account payerAccount;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="recever_account_id")
    private Account receiverAccount;

    /* GETTERS AND SETTERS */

}
```

In this code i use EAGER fetch, it means that your lists will be automatically populated if you have an object account.

Hope it helps.

Comment: On RelationalDb perspective, that scenário you could possibly add duplicate entries for (payer_account_id, recever_account_id). Not sure if you want

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
    //mapping here to Account Entity
    @ManyToOne  
    private Account payerAccount;


    //mapping here to Account Entity
    @ManyToOne
    private Account receiverAccount;
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? "How about this" sounds like you aren't sure this solves the issue