# JPA ManyToMany self bidirectional reference by one field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have one entity User. I need ManyToMany bidirectional relation User-User pairs in one field. How I can do it?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;
    private Set<User> pairs;
}
```

I tried like this:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "pairs", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "a"), 
    @JoinColumn(name = "b")
})
private Set<User> pairs;
```

And got next result: `org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering com.calm.model.entity.User from com.calm.model.entity.User has the wrong number of column. should be 1`

Db scmema generated by ddl:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ...
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

And expected pairs table:

```
CREATE TABLE `pairs` (
    `a` int(11) NOT NULL, //user 1
    `b` int(11) NOT NULL, //user 2
    PRIMARY KEY (`a`,`b`)
)
```

And expected behavior like:

```
SELECT b as id2 FROM pairs WHERE a = :id1
UNION 
SELECT a as id2 FROM pairs WHERE b = :id1
```

Comment: Are you using a join table? Can you provide db schema?

Comment: Well you clearly specified 2 join columns. Maybe this is what you wanted: `@JoinTable(name = "pairs", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "a", referencedColumnName="b")}`

Comment: @AlanHay It throws an exception `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to find column with logical name: b in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(users) and its related supertables and secondary tables`. I think `referencedColumnName` is reference to users table id.

Comment: @Andronicus I was added db tables ddl.

Comment: @Calm, i don't think that mapping to one field is possible - please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32698294/jpa-hibernate-two-foreign-keys-to-the-same-table

Comment: You don't need two join columns, because `User` does not have a composite key. You want one `joinColumn` and one `inverseJoinColumn`